# Can I publish a copy of my answers in other websites?

Tags: support, answers, copyright, licensing, rules

I want to publish only and only my own answers (not others') in other websites and in my own website.

Is there any site rule preventing this?

Answer (score 9):

You license your contribution to Stack Overflow, but it is *still your contribution*, so yes, you can publish your posts elsewhere too.

Note that that does assume the post wasn't significantly altered by someone else in the meantime; at which point you can use the altered post under the CC-BY-SA terms. Your original copy will always be available in the post revisions, of course.

Comment: Even if it was edited, I can browse the history of the answer, and find my original first answer there. It wouldn't be a problem if I take my original first answer if someone had edited it afterwards, right?

Comment: @hkBattousai: Yes, clarified in the answer.